# How Integrating Socket.io 1.x client with c# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, socket.io

SocketIO4Net.Client only supports 0.9 and  SocketIoClientDotNet seems not working.

Is there any way to integrate C # .NET with the latest version of socket.io?

Comment: No.  Socket.IO 1.x used a windows driver for sockets.  When Net 2.0+ was developed Microsoft decided to throw away the windows sockets because there were know errors and decided to rewrite the socket library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SocketIoClientDotNet with socket.io version 1.7.3, https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/blob/master/TestServer/package.json